# Not seeing some directories in windows partition

Tags: mount, xubuntu, ntfs

I installed Xubuntu 14.04 in dual boot with Windows 7 in a Lenovo G480 laptop. I'm having the following issue:

I can't see (literally) a couple of directories which are in the Win partition. To be more precise, I mount the NTFS partition and need to read/write the C:/Users/my_win_user/Documents and another folder with data (C:/Data), but I can't find them even from terminal doing ls or from the file manager. I don't know what I'm missing...

I tried mounting the partition with:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o -rw /dev/sda2 /media/win
```

and

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda2 /media/win -o "umask=022"
```

Both with the same issue.

As a test, I copied the data folder from windows to an external HDD (NTFS), then mounted in Xubuntu and I can see and read/write the directories without any problem.

I can't realize what I'm doing wrong... I searched in `enter code here`the forum but couldn't find the same problem posted.

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Please no crosspostings http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2227025

Comment: Did you check the filesystem under Windows? `Check Disk` will do it.

Comment: Mmmmmh... I think that could be the problem, because since I partitioned de HDD an resized the win partition, when booting in windows, a check disk pops up but it can't be done because it says something about a software package is causing trouble and I should restore to a previous configuration. I won't do that... thanks!!! I will manage using an external HDD.